# Need to write following formula in excel

Tags: excel

```
if answer=='No' and score>high_threshold:
    final_score=3
elif answer=='No' and (score<high_threshold or score>low_threshold): 
    final_score=2
elif (answer=='No' and score<low_threshold) or (answer=='Yes' and score>high_threshold): 
    final_score=1
elif (answer=='Yes' and score<low_threshold)"
    final_score=0
else:
    final_score=0
```

I'm very novice in Excel just got this far

`=IF(AND(F2="No",L2>=high_threshold),"3",IF(L2<high_threshold,L2>low_threshold,"2"))`

Comment: Perhaps `=IF(F2="No",IF(L2>high_threshold,3,IF(L2>low_threshold,2,1)),IF(L2>high_threshold,1,0))`

Comment: Your last `Elseif` is unnecessary since its conditions will be included in the final `Else`

Comment: What if answer=='Yes' and score **>** low_threshold ?

Answer (score 0):

Start by building the formulas one by one. Excel has quite good tool-tip system. Take a look (`WENN()` means `IF()`; `ODER()` means `OR()`):

[image]

[image]

At the end try to evaluate the formula using Ribbon > Formulas > Evaluate:

[image]